# Loop audio a limited number of times

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, mediaelement

I am trying to play music in my web browser under a certain condition, threshold = true for 10 iteration and here is my code:

```
<script>
var threshold = true;
for (var i=0 ; i<10; i++){// number of iteration
    if ( threshold){
          var audio = new Audio('song.mp3');
          audio.play();
    } 
}
</script>
```

while I don't get any error the song won't be played in my browser; therefore I don't know what can possibly be wrong.

Comment: Note that in your code, your loops are all going to run immediately.  You're attempting to start 10 audio elements all simultaneously.  The browser doesn't know that you actually want to wait after `audio.play()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. I got the error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't generally call `audio.play()` unless you're doing it in immediate response to some sort of user action.  This is due to the [autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Next, I would leave the looping up to the browser:

```
audio.loop = true;
```

Now, use the `seeked` event to figured out when the audio went back in time.  (Most likely, it looped.)  When this happens, increment a loop count.  Then, see if we've looped too many times and pause if so.

```
 let maxLoops = 10;
 let lastTime = 0;
 let loops = 0;
 audio.addEventListener('seeked', (e) => {
   if (e.target.currentTime < lastTime) {
     loops++;
   }
   if (loops >= maxLoops) {
     e.target.pause();
   }
   lastTime = e.target.currentTime;
 });
```

Comment: There is the `seek` event that should fire at each loop.